# pandoc.brew() does not work in rmarkdown

Tags: r-markdown, pandoc

I am trying to use Pandoc.brew() in an .Rmd file, but the result is not as it should be. Now I've been looking for some sort of example .Rmd file that uses Pandoc.brew(), but I can't find it anywhere, which makes me wonder whether I am using Pandoc.brew() correctly. Below is an MWE:

````
---
title: "Foo"
date: "30 november 2015"
output: html_document
---

```{r}
library(pander)
```

```{r pander, results = "asis"}
m <- mtcars[1:2, 1:3]
pandoc.table(m)


text <- paste('# Header', '',
  'What a lovely list:\n<%=as.list(runif(10))%>',
  'A wide table:\n<%=mtcars[1:3, ]%>',
  'And a nice chart:\n\n<%=plot(1:10)%>', sep = '\n')

Pandoc.brew(text = text)
```
````

And the result is this:

[image]

So my main question is: am I using Pandoc.brew() correctly, and if not, what do I need to change so that this .Rmd file will properly show the table and the figure?

Answer (score 0):

Why would you use `Pandoc.brew` inside of a `knitr` or `rmarkdown` document? All of these functions and approaches do pretty much the same. If you want to stick with `Pandoc.brew`, create a file (e.g. `foo.brew`) with the below content and call `Pandoc.brew('foo.brew', output = 'foo', convert = 'html')`:

```
% Foo
% 30 november 2015

<%=
m <- mtcars[1:2, 1:3]
pandoc.table(m)
%>

# Header

What a lovely list:

<%= as.list(runif(10)) %>

A wide table:

<%= mtcars[1:3, ] %>

And a nice chart:

<%= plot(1:10) %>
```

Alternatively, you can use `pander` (to convert R objects into markdown) inside of `knitr` or an `rmarkdown` document via the [general S3 method](http://rapporter.github.io/pander/#generic-pander-method) -- optionally setting `pander` to be the default rendering method as a general `knitr` option.